# On the issue of automatic time series fitting using R

Tags: r, time-series, curve-fitting

we have to fit about 2000 or odd time series every month,
they have very idiosyncratic behavior in particular, some are arma/arima, some are ewma, some are arch/garch with or without seasonality and/or trend (only thing in common is the time series aspect).

one can in theory build ensemble model with aic or bic criterion to choose the best fit model but is the community aware of any library which attempts to solve this problem?

Google made me aware of the below one by Rob J Hyndman
[link](http://robjhyndman.com/software/forecast)

but are they any other alternatives?

Comment: The link to my forecast package is incorrect. It should be http://robjhyndman.com/software/forecast

Comment: apologize and so corrected, thanks for writing the package BTW

Answer (score 3):

There are two automatic methods in the [forecast package](http://robjhyndman.com/software/forecast): `auto.arima()` which will handle automatic modelling using ARIMA models, and `ets()` which will automatically select the best model from the exponential smoothing family (including trend and seasonality where appropriate). The AIC is used in both cases for model selection. Neither handles ARCH/GARCH models though. The package is described in some detail in this JSS article: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v27/i03

Further to your question:

> *When will it be possible to use
>   forecast package functions, especially
>   ets function, with high dimensional
>   data(weekly data, for example)?*

Probably early next year. The paper is written (see robjhyndman.com/working-papers/complex-seasonality) and we are working on the code now.

Comment: Rob: It looks like auto.arima() only works with ts objects.  Any thoughts about allowing it to accept other irregular time series (e.g. with zoo)?  As a simple example with the quantmod package: { getSymbols("GS"); auto.arima(as.zoo(GS[,'GS.Close'])) }

Comment: No. ARIMA models for irregularly spaced data are very tricky. Essentially you need to fit a continuous time ARMA (see papers by Brockwell et al) which is a very different sort of model than the discrete time counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks useRs, I have tried the forecast package, that too as a composite of arima and ets, but not to much acclaim from aic or bic(sbc), so i am now tempted to treat each of the time series to its own svm(support vector machine) because of its better genralization adaptability and also being able to add other variables apart from lags and non linear kernel functions

Any premonitions?

Comment: You can't compare the AIC from ARIMA and ETS as they are based on different datasets due to differencing. Also, I have seen no evidence that svm is a good general time series forecasting algorithm. For example, the forecasting M-competitions have shown that non-linear data mining methods tend to perform worse than the linear statistical models on large sets of univariate time series data. There is quite a lot of literature on this. I suggest you read the papers associated with the M3 competition before you try to come up with your own untested method.