# Information criterions in exp smoothing models

Tags: r, time-series

What are the numbers of parameters to be penalized for when using information criterions(BIC or AIC or..) for selecting the best models? Let's say that we have 3 models: 1. Simple exponential smoothing 2. Holt's method(level+trend) 3. Holt Winters(L+T+S), where we have monthly seasonality. How many parameters for penalization does have each model?

Comment: I don't think this is an R question or a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that this is not an R question, but it is, nevertheless, a valid time-series question. As far as I know, the theory is not very clear on how the IC is calculated for exponential smoothing models. But there have been few studies. See, for example, [this paper](http://www.buseco.monash.edu.au/ebs/pubs/wpapers/2005/wp6-05.pdf). See also Prof. Hyndman's comment to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401872/on-the-issue-of-automatic-time-series-fitting-using-r/1402739#1402739).

Be careful - don't use IC to compare between, for e.g., exponential smoothing and ARIMA models. See the comment in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401872/on-the-issue-of-automatic-time-series-fitting-using-r/1415983#1415983).